# Function as element of a set

Tags: functions, notation

Can anyone tell me what does the following notation represent $$f \in C^2[a,b]$$ in terms of function notation?

I suppose $[a,b]$ means the function is defined in that interval, but I am confused with the '$f \in$' notation.

Comment: $\in$ can be read as *is a member of*

Comment: often written $\mathscr C$

Answer (score 2):

$C^n[a,b]$ is the set of all functions defined in $[a,b]$ that have up to n-order continuous derivatives. So the notation means that both $f'$ and $f''$ exist and are continuous.

Comment: It might be good to more fully express the answer - e.g. something like "The notation means that $f$ is a function defined on $[a,b]$ so that $f'$ and $f''$ exist and are are continuous." It's seems kind of awkward as written.

Comment: Yes, this is right - you will also sometimes see $C^\infty [a, b]$ which means smooth functions, i.e. functions with derivatives of all orders on $[a, b]$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness. Also sometimes you will not see the $[a, b]$ right there, in cases where the relevant interval or set is mentioned nearby.